# How to configure django server and react server to AWS elastic beanstalk service at the same time

Tags: python, django, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am wondering how to setup and connect python server and react.js server to aws beanstalk at the same time. Ask someone who has some experience.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "react.js server" unless you want to server-side render your react components. Aside from that you really just need the django server to serve the static react assets - or just put them in a S3 bucket directly.

Answer (score 0):

There's a boilerplate framework with Django on the server, React on the client. Running the build in the client automatically dumps the distribution assets into Django's static assets. I hope you find it useful. I unfortunately don't have any answers on how to connect the app to beanstalk though.

Here's the repo: https://github.com/rafay826/djudo